# While sending mail using PHP mail() function, Japanese header text is not shown in readable format

Tags: php, email

I am using PHP `mail()` function to send mail. **Headers include Japanese text.** Mail was sent and all body text (Japanese text) is readable **except the header text (Japanese text)**. I am using following code to send mail.

```
$test_admin_email="test@test.com";
$test_admin_headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n" ;
$test_admin_headers .= "From: 株式会社テスト <test@test.com>\n";
$test_admin_headers .= "Reply-To: 株式会社テ<reply@test@test.com>\n";
$test_admin_headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\n";

$test_user_headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n" ;
$test_user_headers .= "From: 株式会社テスト <test@test.com>\n";
$test_user_headers .= "Reply-To: 株式会社テスト <test@test.com>\n";
$test_user_headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\n";

$res=mail($test_admin_email, $test_admin_subject, $test_admin_message, $test_admin_headers);

@mail($user_email, $test_user_subject, $test_user_message, $test_user_headers);
```

I want to show the readable Japanese headers in both user and admin email.

I am currently getting unreadable text format in header section (having Japanese text). But all other section (having japanese text) is displaying in readable format.

Comment: have you tried CJK encoding instead of utf8- just a thought

Comment: I tried CJK encoding too, that also didn't work. Above code works well in gmail, hotmail. The problem is in outlook mail.

Comment: i copy and paste your code tested on a local server and it worked fine - outlook. not sure that helps but you may want to check your outlook settings

Comment: Other Japanese mail is readable. So, I think I do not have to change  outlook settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I am able to pass readable Japanese text through header. And it works fine on outlook mail too. I added mb_encode_mimeheader() code to encode the japanese text as shown in below code:

```
$test_admin_email="test@test.com";
$test_admin_headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n" ;
$test_admin_headers .= "From: 株式会社テスト <test@test.com>\n";
$test_admin_headers .= "Reply-To: 株式会社テ<reply@test@test.com>\n";
$test_admin_headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\n";


$from = mb_encode_mimeheader("株式会社テスト", "ISO-2022-JP"); //newly added code.
$replyTo = mb_encode_mimeheader("株式会社テスト", "ISO-2022-JP"); //newly added code.

$test_user_headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n" ;
$test_user_headers .= "From: $from <test@test.com>\n";
$test_user_headers .= "Reply-To: $replyTo <test@test.com>\n";
$test_user_headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\n";

  $res=mail($test_admin_email, $test_admin_subject, $test_admin_message, $test_admin_headers);

  @mail($user_email, $test_user_subject, $test_user_message, $test_user_headers);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/ja/function.mail.php